# Question about older MS C/C++ format specifiers

Tags: visual-c++

Came across some code that was causing a crash. It's ancient (from 90s or older), but started manifesting recently with a newer compiler. Some of this code is using sprintf with a format specifier like:

```
sprintf(buf, "here is some stuff %ld pieces of %ld samples from %Fs", someIntValue, someOtherIntValue, someCharStarPointer);
```

The third argument is the cause of the crash... According to the docs, %F is for a float and it will just print an s after the the floating point number.

My question, was %Fs ever a valid format for old versions of Microsoft's compiler? Like maybe when there were mixed memory models and the F could have been to signify that it was a far pointer? IDK, grasping at straws. Obviously we're going to fix the %Fs to just use %s, but I was wondering if old timers remember anything like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [FreeDos sources](https://github.com/joyent/sdcboot/blob/master/freedos/source/sys37/kernel/prf.c#L265):

```
STATIC void do_printf(CONST BYTE FAR * fmt, va_list arg)
{
    ...
    case 's':
        p = va_arg(arg, char *);
        break;
    case 'F':
        fmt++;
        /* we assume %Fs here */
    case 'S':
        p = va_arg(arg, char FAR *);
        break;
```

So, you are right about `%Fs` being used for FAR pointers.

Comment: Thanks. I just tried an example with Visual Studio 2013 and my code with %Fs worked just fine--it printed the string. Tried with VS 2017 and it warned me about the format specifier and then failed on execution--well, it did what it was supposed to do. A lot of our format strings are in resources so that we can localize them...so they aren't subject to the compile time format checks.

Comment: I stepped through the VC++ source on a sprintf and found my answer in output.c in Microsoft's CRT (for Visual Studio 2013). They don't specifically say it's for a FAR pointer, but they treat it as a size modifier and then they do nothing with it.